# Проблема с генерацией карты

Tags: python, pygame

Я делаю генерацию карты. Для этого я создал класс Room, который представляет из себя набор Rect'ов (атрибут geometry) определенного цвета. Атрибут rect - это прямоугольник, в который помещаются все Rect'ы из атрибута geometry.

```
class Room:
    def __init__(self, rect: pygame.Rect, color: pygame.Color):
        self.rect: pygame.Rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
        self.geometry: list[pygame.Rect] = [rect]
        self.color: pygame.Color = color
```

Есть класс Door, который соединяет две комнаты.

```
class Door:
    def __init__(self, pos: list[int, int], first_room: Room, second_room: Room):
        self.pos: list[int, int] = pos
        self.first_room: Room = first_room
        self.second_room: Room = second_room
```

Класс Flat - набор дверей и комнат.

```
class Flat:
    def __init__(self, start_room):
        self.rooms: list[Room] = [start_room]
        self.doors: list[Door] = []
```

И класс FlatGenerator, который и генерирует карту при вызове метода generate.

```
class FlatGenerator:
    def __init__(self, room_count: int):
        self.room_count: int = room_count
```

Проблема в том, что я могу добавить дверь только при создании новой комнаты.
[image: Пример генерации]

То есть зеленая и бордовая комнаты не соединены дверью. Мне придется проходиться по каждому Rect'у каждой комнаты и искать общие грани или есть более элегантные пути решения?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности: «проблемы с тем-то» — это очень плохой заголовок.